# Why this async/await code doesn't deadlock

Tags: c#, async-await

I am reading [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) article about deadlock, and I tried with my own code and it doesn't have deadlock issue. Why is that?

I am expecting:

1. `GetJsonAsync` finishes await and about to return `jsonString`
2. `Main` is executing `jsonTask.Result` and hold the context
3. `GetJsonAsync` wants to return `jsonString` until context is available
4. deadlock will happen

   ```
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var jsonTask = GetJsonAsync();
           int i = jsonTask.Result;
           Console.WriteLine(jsonTask.Result);
       }

       public static async Task<int> GetJsonAsync()
       {
           var jsonString = await ReturnIntAsync();
           return jsonString;
       }

       public static async Task<int> ReturnIntAsync()
       {
           int i = 0;
           await Task.Run(() => i++);
           return i;
       }
   ```

Comment: Console applications do not have a SynchronizationContext, therefore, no context switch deadlock is provoked. The article clearly says "UI Example" and then "ASP.NET example"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks for replying, I added int assign, but still no deadlock

Comment: You mean in main function, there is no SynchronizationContext?

Comment: No, the SynchronizationContext is dependent on the framework you use, and those are numbered: WinForms, WPF, Xamarin and ASP.NET WebForms (as far as I remember)

Comment: Please read this blog post by *Stephen Toub (Mr. Parallel)* [Parallel Programming with .NET - await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't deadlock because there's no synchronizing `SynchronizationContext`, so the `async` method resumes executing on a thread pool thread, not the main thread.

Relevant quotes from the article (emphasis added):

> Here’s the situation: remember from my intro post that after you await a Task, when the method continues it will continue in a context.
>
> In the first case, this context is a UI context (which applies to any UI **except Console applications**). In the second case, this context is an ASP.NET request context...
>
> For the UI example, the “context” is the UI context; for the ASP.NET example, the “context” is the ASP.NET request context. This type of deadlock can be caused for either “context”.

If you really want to deadlock a Console application this way, you can use `AsyncContext` [from my `AsyncEx` library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) to install a single-threaded context on the main thread of your Console app.

Comment: How about Unity3D? Is there SynchronizationContext?

Comment: @weijia_yu: I don't know. You can check `SynchronizationContext.Current` to see.